# Mapping keys to values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

Working on getting dictionary keys and values to line up correctly.

```
import pprint

old_dict = {'A B':['C D'],'E F':['G H'],'I J':['K L'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
new_dict = {}

for x in old_dict:
    try:
        for i in range(0,2):
            key = x.split()[i]
            value = old_dict[x][0].split()[i]
            new_dict[key] = value
    except:
        pass

pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```

The above code works fine and returns:

```
{'A': 'C',
 'B': 'D',
 'E': 'G',
 'F': 'H',
 'I': 'K',
 'J': 'L',
 'M': 'O',
 'N': 'P',
 'Q': 'S',
 'R': 'T',
 'U': 'W',
 'V': 'X'}
```

The only issue is when I change old_dict to be the following:

```
old_dict = {'AB':['C D'],'E F':['GH'],'IJ':['KL'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
```

It returns:

```
{'AB': 'C',
 'E': 'GH',
 'IJ': 'KL',
 'M': 'O',
 'N': 'P',
 'Q': 'S',
 'R': 'T',
 'U': 'W',
 'V': 'X'}
```

I'd like to skip over the keys that are not space delimited paired up with space delimited values, and also skip over the values that are not space delimited paired up with space delimited keys (i.e., I want to skip over 'AB': 'C', 'E': 'GH', - the rest in the above example are okay).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pprint
old_dict = {'AB':['C D'],'E F':['GH'],'I J':['K L'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
new_dict = {}

for x in old_dict:
    for i in range(0,2):
      if ' ' in x:
        key = x.split()[i]
      else:
        key = x.replace("", " ")[1:-1]
        key = key.split()[i]
      if ' ' in old_dict[x][0]:
        value = old_dict[x][0].split()[i]
      else:
        value = old_dict[x][0].replace("", " ")[1:-1]
        value = value.split()[i]

      new_dict[key] = value

pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on my phone, so I can't really test it right now, but this should do it:

```
d = {'A B':['C D'],'E F':['G H'],'I J':['K L'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
answer = {}

for k in d:
    k = k.split()
    if len(k) == 1: continue
    v = d[k][0].split()
    if len(v) == 1: continue

    for a,b in zip(k,v):
        answer[a] = b
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested it works fine:

```
import pprint

old_dict = {'AB':['C D'],'E F':['GH'],'I J':['K L'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
new_dict = {}

for x in old_dict:
    try:
        for i in range(0,2):
            key = x.split()[i]
            if len(key) == 1:
                if len(old_dict[x][0].split()[i]) == 1:
                    value = old_dict[x][0].split()[i]
            new_dict[key] = value
    except:
        pass

pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint

old_dict = {'AB':['C D'],'E F':['GH'],'IJ':['KL'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
new_dict = {}

for x in old_dict:
    try:
        if(len(x)==len(old_dict[x][0])):
            for i in range(0,2):
                key = x.split()[i]
                value = old_dict[x][0].split()[i]
                new_dict[key] = value
    except:
        pass


pprint.pprint(new_dict)
```

Comment: Is this {'IJ': 'KL', 'M': 'O', 'N': 'P', 'Q': 'S', 'R': 'T', 'U': 'W', 'V': 'X'} u need??

Answer (score 0):

You could use dict comprehension:

```
>>> old_dict = {'AB':['C D'],'E F':['GH'],'IJ':['KL'],'M N':['O P'],'Q R':['S T'], 'U V':['W X']}
>>> {x: y for k, v in old_dict.items() if len(k) == len(v[0]) for x, y in zip(k.split(), v[0].split())}
{'M': 'O', 'N': 'P', 'Q': 'S', 'IJ': 'KL', 'U': 'W', 'V': 'X', 'R': 'T'}
```